# Can't get the meaning

Tags: meaning, translation

http://www.restaurantbusinessonline.com/operations/technology/are-digital-menus-way-go
I can't understand the meaning of 2nd part in this sentence. What changes?      what has that to do with running out smth in the kitchen.

Or if the kitchen runs out of something, “we’re never more than five minutes away from making those changes.”

Comment: ... digital signage [gives] the ability to link with [the] POS system: “Pricing can adjust (ie be adjusted) with the click of a button” // If the kitchen runs out of something, we can adjust the menu to remove non-available courses within five minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the full quote:

> “Pricing can adjust with the click of a button,” he says. Or if the
>   kitchen runs out of something, “we’re never more than five minutes
>   away from making those changes.”

The changes refer to necessary changes to the menu, which can be made quickly because it's a digital menu, not a paper one.  If the kitchen runs out of an entree, the menu can be updated to either delete the offering or note that it's no longer available.